# Setting SAS date to UTC/GMT from external query

Tags: sas

I am using `Proc SQL` to pull in a date that is stored as GMT in SQL Server. I want SAS to recognize the value as GMT/UTC so I can format later on to account for users time zone.

Is there an informat I can use to set the SQL Server date to GMT in SAS?

Comment: I think I agree that is a duplicate.  @OP, you'll find that SAS doesn't really think of a date as belonging to a particular time zone - you have to assume it is in your code, basically.

Comment: @Joe - How do I force a time to be "GMT"?

Comment: You don't, as far as I understand.  Times are just times, they are timezoneless.  You can display a time with a time zone offset if you want (with a format).